# Unsupported operating system

Tags: java, jxbrowser

JxBrowser in Windows 10 cause "Unsupported operating system". I can overcome this error using `System.setProperty("os.name", "Windows 8.1");`. However, are there any configuration in JX-Browser side to overcome this issue?

(I'm using JX browser 6.6.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you upgrade your JRE. I suppose you use an old JRE that doesn't recognize Windows 10 via the "os.name" System Property. JxBrowser uses the "os.name" System Property to determine OS name and version, so it totally depends on your JRE version.

Comment: At the moment it is impossible to change the JRE. I'm using 1.6 and it returns Windows NT (unknown) as os.name. I will use the workaround since there is no alternative solution.